# How can I locate a local html file that has been loaded into the browsers element inspector?

Tags: html, local, webm, locate

Since there don't seem to be any video players with a seamless loop, I've been opening my webms through Firefox since the webm player is capable of seamless looping. Problem is every time I open a webm I have to manually edit the video tag in the html through the element inspector. I want to find this file and edit it directly so that I can save it and keep it that way. But I don't see any obvious way to do that and it's proven a tricky task to string together the right keywords in the right order on google.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no HTML file which one can edit to change the looping, this would have to be edited in source, and recompiled. [Source Code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/html/VideoDocument.cpp#110).
This is done by adding the line `element->SetLoop(true);` around line 110. [Function Definition](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/html/HTMLMediaElement.h#485).

If you'd prefer not to edit source, from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/993718, `javascript:var vids=document.getElementsByTagName("video"); for (i=0; i<vids.length; i++) vids[i].setAttribute("loop", "true"); void 0;` can be saved as a bookmarklet to be run; or [WhatIsThisImNotGoodWithComputers](https://github.com/WhatIsThisImNotGoodWithComputers), on GitHub, has created a GreaseMonkey [Script](https://github.com/WhatIsThisImNotGoodWithComputers/webm-looper-userscript) which automates the loop attribute setting.

Comment: Brilliant response Logan. You answered my question, offered three alternative solutions, and assumed nothing about my knowledge. Thank you!

Comment: I decided to go with the user script engine, because I imagine I'll have several uses for such a solution in the future. I installed grease monkey, installed the script from the link you gave me. Grease monkey notified me that the script installed correctly and I gave it a go bu loading a webm I had handy. It isn't working though. So I examined the script myself. Turns out it's exactly the same as the script you offered in your answer as a bookmarklet solution. So I'm guessing I'm just doing something wrong, because everything else seems to be in order.

Comment: The GitHub page mentions that enabling GreaseMonkey on local pages requires a change in Firefox's configuration: [Link](https://github.com/WhatIsThisImNotGoodWithComputers/webm-looper-userscript#enabling-local-files-on-greasemonkey)